# MSSQL Server Why group by alias doesn't work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to solve the question in leetcode [1699. Number of Calls Between Two Persons](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-calls-between-two-persons/). My solution doesn't work and it gives an error saying `[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'person1'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)` How can I fix it?

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN to_id
        ELSE from_id
    END AS person1,
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN from_id
        ELSE to_id
    END AS person2,
    COUNT(duration) AS call_count,
    SUM(duration) AS total_duration
FROM Calls
GROUP BY person1, person2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-queries are used to allow you to define 'scope'...

```
SELECT
  person1,
  person2,
  COUNT(duration) AS call_count,
  SUM(duration) AS total_duration
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN to_id
        ELSE from_id
    END AS person1,
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN from_id
        ELSE to_id
    END AS person2,
    duration
  FROM
    Calls
)
  C
GROUP BY
  person1,
  person2
```

An alternative is to use `APPLY`

```
SELECT 
  P.person1,
  P.person2,
  COUNT(C.duration) AS call_count,
  SUM(C.duration) AS total_duration
FROM
  CALLS AS C
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN C.from_id > C.to_id THEN C.to_id
        ELSE C.from_id
    END AS person1,
    CASE 
        WHEN C.from_id > C.to_id THEN C.from_id
        ELSE C.to_id
    END AS person2
)
  AS P
GROUP BY
  P.person1,
  P.person2
```

Answer (score 0):

From_Id and to id need to be the group by.  I would bring in your case logic and duration into one query and then apply your aggregate to the outer part.

```
SELECT
    X.Person1
    , X.Person2
    ,COUNT(X.duration) AS call_count
    ,SUM(X.duration) AS total_duration

FROM
(

SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN to_id
        ELSE from_id
    END AS person1,
    CASE 
        WHEN from_id > to_id THEN from_id
        ELSE to_id
    END AS person2,
    duration

FROM Calls
) AS X

GROUP BY
    X.Person1
    , X.Person2
```